# Laravel - orderBy name on relationship with map function

Tags: php, laravel

i am looking for solution to sort alphabetically list of manufacturers using relationship, `map` function and `toArray()`. Here is code sample:

```
$manufacturers = Manufacturer::with('translation')
->get()
->map(function ($m) {
      return ['key' => $m->getName(), 'value' => $m->id];
      })
->pluck('key', 'value')
->prepend('Choose manufaturer', '')
->toArray();
```

And later on in view select list is created:

[image]

I have tried to add orderBy to translation like this:

```
$manufacturers = Manufacturer::with(['translation' => function ($q) {
  $q->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
}])->get()  
// code cutted here (same as above)
```

Code shows no error but it's not ordering. I guess that each manufacturer collection has it's own translation and it's ordering in each manufacturer than in whole list.

Here is dd($manufacturers):

[image]

I am thinking also about two solutions - add join to query as few other devs did on stackoverflow or sort in php which seems bad idea. Is there any 'simple' solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `orderBy` after `get`?

Comment: If not maybe consider doing a left join instead of `=> function ($q)`